# How to make Infinispan work with camel

Tags: java, caching, intellij-idea, apache-camel, infinispan

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.infinispan.InfinispanConstants;
import org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonLibrary;
import uk.co.sammy.model.Collection;

public class InfinispanRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private JacksonDataFormat json = new JacksonDataFormat(Collection.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:src/data?noop=true&include=.*.json")
                .choice()
                .when()
                .jsonpath("$..CustInfo[?(@.firstName == 'Sammy')]").unmarshal(json)
                .log("Got customer data for ${body.custInfo.firstName}")
                .setHeader(InfinispanConstants.OPERATION, constant(InfinispanConstants.PUT_IF_ABSENT))
                .setHeader(InfinispanConstants.KEY, simple("${body.custInfo.firstName}"))
                .to("infinispan://localhost")
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                .to("activemq:queue:incomingApplication", "activemq:queue:customerDetails");

        from("activemq:queue:incomingApplication")
                .setHeader(InfinispanConstants.OPERATION, constant(InfinispanConstants.GET))
                .setHeader(InfinispanConstants.KEY, constant("${body.custInfo.firstName}"))
                .to("infinispan://foo?cacheName=localCache")
                .setBody(simple("${header.CamelInfinispanOperationResult}"))
                .to("activemq:output");
    }
}
```

My pom.xml looks like the below

```
<properties>
        <activemq.version>5.14.1</activemq.version>
        <camel.version>2.18.0</camel.version>
        <infinispan.version>8.3.0.Final-redhat-1</infinispan.version>
        <camel-jbossdatagrid.version>6.6.1.Final-redhat-1</camel-jbossdatagrid.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jbossdatagrid</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-jbossdatagrid.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--ActiveMQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>fuse-release</id>
            <name>jboss Release Repository</name>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I have tried for three days to get this simple sample code to work with Infinispan using the REdhat getting started guide and downloaded the quickstart zip to run that but still won't work! I keep getting the error "*cannot connect to foo:11222*" or "*pool not open*" by Spring JMS then a warning about mixing Uber and Jars version. I started off using ehcache which was a pain to implement because of limited simple examples that show how to store, retrieve and clear a cache from rest calls etc. Now, I need this to work so I can easily migrate it to Openshift but, still won't work! Every time I restart the project, I get different errors. Please any help to step by step setup Infinispan to work using my above code will be SERIOUSLY appreciated. Thanks guys!

P.S: I've read through the Redhat data grid getting started page and followed their instructions before doing this as my last resort!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "infinispan://localhost" uri format will try to connect to an Infinispan server. To use an embedded cache, you should use something like "infinispan://?cacheName=localCache"

Comment: I've tried that and it still doesn't work. :( I get this _org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager start_ and it just hangs the code processing there. I've got the Infinispan server running but can't seem to use the _.addServer()_ as that's always marked red & not able to find the maven dependency to solve that either.

Comment: It is still not clear to me if you want to use embedded or client/server mode.

Comment: I was using the client/server mode but, I've gone a different route from the code above because I wanted to work with the cache as a separate process though integrated with the routing using a bean declaration. Why I was having that issue was because, I used a newer client version to the server version.

Comment: I've got a different issue though, I need to configure two cache instances that can reference each other where one holds the reference of keys and the other holds the objects stored along with a key common in both cache instances to create that link but not found any example on defining two caches using RemoteCacheManager or ConfigurationBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few errors in the example you have provided:

1st route:

- You should set the value you want to put in the cache with InfinispanConstants.VALUE

2nd route:

- You should use the same cache uses by the first route (i.e. same cache name)
- You should use simple to set InfinispanConstants.KEY

Comment: Okay, that's definitely cleared up some confusion I had on which constants to use though now, I've gone down the route of using it as a Java class which makes it much more easier to manage and work with.